# ggplot for a histogram with negative values in different color

Tags: r, ggplot2

i'd like to produce two histogram on the same scale y-axis, here is my attempt:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyverse)
library(gridExtra)

dat_url <- 'https://gender-pay-gap.service.gov.uk/viewing/download-data/2019'
dat <- read_csv(dat_url) 

p1 <- dat %>% 
  filter(between(DiffMedianHourlyPercent,-100,100)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = DiffMedianHourlyPercent)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = ..count..), binwidth = 2)

p2 <- dat %>% 
  filter(between(DiffMeanHourlyPercent,-100,100)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = DiffMeanHourlyPercent)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = ..count..), binwidth = 2)

grid.arrange(p1, p2, nrow = 1)
```

Also, i'd love the negative values to be in another color similar to this plot:

[image: proper]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to color the parts different for values >0 and <=0, you can just change the `fill=` aesthetic. For example for one plot, you can do

```
dat %>% 
  filter(between(DiffMedianHourlyPercent,-100,100)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = DiffMedianHourlyPercent)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = DiffMedianHourlyPercent>0), binwidth = 2) + 
  guides(fill=FALSE)
```

(here we also turn off the legend)

[image]

Note the some of the bins you have chosen contain both positive and negative values. If you don't want that, you can take control of the bin locations yourself

```
dat %>% 
  filter(between(DiffMedianHourlyPercent,-100,100)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = DiffMedianHourlyPercent)) + 
  geom_histogram(aes(fill = DiffMedianHourlyPercent>0), 
                 breaks=seq(-100, 100, by=2)) + 
  guides(fill=FALSE)
```

[image]